# How to override the alignment of a VStack if all component don't have fixed frames?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an `HStack`, aligned `top`, with 3 components. I want the first `Text` to be pushed to the bottom, essentially overriding the `HStack`'s alignment.

I want the `Text` to keep its intrinsic size and override its parent's alignment.

[image]

```
HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
    Text("BOTTOM")
        .font(.system(size: 24))
        .background {
            Color.yellow
        }

    Spacer()

    Text("TOP ")
        .background {
            Color.blue
        }

    Spacer()

    Text("X")
        .font(.system(size: 40))
        .background {
            Color.green
        }
}
.background {
    Color.red
}
```

I can wrap the `Text` in a `VStack` and add a `Spacer` before it but that will only work if

1. there is a fixed frame height on the `Text` OR
2. there is a fixed frame height on the `HStack`

If I don't have either and still add a `Spacer`, the `Spacer` stretches to take up the entire screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Create two `HStack`s, the outermost aligned to the bottom, while an inner one wraps the second block, aligning everything to the top.

Here:

```
// Align the whole block to the bottom
HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
    Text("BOTTOM")
        .font(.system(size: 24))
        .background {
            Color.yellow
        }

    // The sub-block is aligned to the top: create
    // a new HStack
    HStack(alignment: .top) {

        Spacer()

        Text("TOP ")
            .background {
                Color.blue
            }

        Spacer()

        Text("X")
            .font(.system(size: 40))
            .background {
                Color.green
            }
    }
}
.background {
    Color.red
}
```

[image]